# Android landscape layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm designing an app and I was just wondering how to make a different layout when in landscape mode. I created a folder in the res called "layout-land" and created an xml file but it does not work when I run the emulator. I tried calling it "main" but it says that already exists, which it does but in the "layout" folder. If I call it something different do I need to change something in the manifest? Thanks for the help!

Comment: no what you are doing is just fine check the spelling of folder and xml files again.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility

Comment: Not exactly get your question. But android automatically changes the layout on orientation change untill you are not overriding onConfigurationChage in your activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to clarify, if you are in landscape or portrait Android looks for the layout file in either the `-land` directory first, if it's not found then it checks the default `layout` directory. Your files should be named as follows, and will be loaded by the system depending at runtime on the device's current configuration:

```
res/layout/main.xml
res/layout-land/main.xml
```

Check the documentation on [**providing resources**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, as I said though when I right click on the layout-land folder and click new android xml file I can't name it "main" it says that already exists but it doesn't in that folder

Comment: Hi rsay3, did Alex actually solve your problem? I am doing TheNewBoston tutorials and having the same problem. I have both layout and layout-land directories. layout-land ist empty, and if I look at the folder in eclipse it is correctly mapped to the layout-land directory. I still have the problem. Might be an eclipse error. I had to solve it by copying the file from layout to layout-land, and refreshing eclipse.

Comment: Ahh, http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-11%E2%80%93Device-Orientation explains it. Eclipse ignores the directory you right click on, and assumes you want to create a file in land. You can ignore the error, then select landscape, and it will update the directory it thinks the file should be saved in.

Comment: oh, ok. sometimes i feel like i don't even know how eclipse works half the time :P. sorry if my answer wasn't very helpful... it kind of explains the theory behind how dynamic layout loading works rather than pinpointing a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want a folder structure like this:

```
res\layout\main.xml
res\layout-land\main.xml
```

Each of these layouts should contain the same elements but re-arranged, e.g. if you have a button with `android:id="@+id/button1"` in the portrait landscape you will need to give an equivalent button in landscape mode the same name.

Answer (score 1):

First you must listen for confguration changes by adding to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Then you can override this function and use setContentView

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

Comment: what to check in this function?